# Protobuf C++ required fields are not checked/enforced

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am new to Protocol Buffers and currently I see the following problem:

We use `proto2` syntax with Protocol Buffers 3.2.0 library and observe that `required` fields are not enforced during the serialization.

Here a basic example with Catch C++ tests:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package simple_test;

message SimpleMessage
{
  required string field1 = 1;
  required string field2 = 2;
}
```

---

```
#include "simple.pb.h"
#include <catch.hpp>
#include <string>

SCENARIO("Verify that serialization with missing required fields fails", "[protobuf]")
{
  GIVEN("a message")
  {
    simple_test::SimpleMessage m;

    WHEN("field1 is set and field2 is not and both are required")
    {
      m.set_field1("aaa");

      THEN("serializing this message to string buffer must fail")
      {
        std::string buffer;
        CHECK_FALSE(m.SerializeToString(&buffer));
        REQUIRE(buffer.empty());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`m.SerializeToString(&buffer)` returns `true` and `buffer.empty()` is `false`.

#### What I know

`required` fields were removed in Protobuf v3.

#### My Questions

- Is there a setting or any kind of config switch that I can enforce these checks with Protobuf v3?
- What happens with the use case:

  `proto2` Message compiled with Protobuf v3 compiler. This message ends up with partially filled required fields and is going to be send to Protobuf v2 enpoint which enforces the `required` fields. Does this effectively mean that there were just bytes sent for nothing, because the message is invalid and will be rejected?
- Should I downgrade from v3.2.0 to 2.x to disallow sending of incomplete messages at client side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came along this documentation which I've overseen before:

[Standard Message Methods](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial#standard-message-methods) and there is the documentation for:

> ### Standard Message Methods
>
> Each message class also contains a number of other methods that let you check or manipulate the entire message, including:
>
> `bool IsInitialized() const;`: checks if all the required fields have been set.

This is what I needed! Protobuf are great again!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a setting or any kind of config switch that I can enforce these checks with Protobuf v3?

Have you tried building protobuf in debug config? I think you'll find that it'll assert in this case.

> What happens with the use case:
>
> proto2 Message compiled with Protobuf v3 compiler. This message ends up with partially filled required fields and is going to be send to Protobuf v2 enpoint which enforces the required fields. Does this effectively mean that there were just bytes sent for nothing, because the message is invalid and will be rejected?

In this case, the receiver can `ParsePartialFromXXX` to received what was sent. He can test message validity with `message.has_xxx()`

> Should I downgrade from v3.2.0 to 2.x to disallow sending of incomplete messages at client side?

I wouldn't. Perhaps write a checker for each message type to assert that each required field is present. Better yet, think about it the proto3 way and treat a missing field as a default value in the receiver. The protobuf documentation advises never adding `required` fields to an existing message type and suggests 'thinking very carefully' before making fields `required`. You could take this to mean 'oops, the concept of required fields was an error'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, even if it disappoints me in terms of how Protobuf mutated. Debug mode is not an option, even if I find that it asserts what than? Regarding the other 2 questions, I read about required fields and in our case I don't want to have any kind of flexible protocol. This should be either "my way or highway". I also read that even at Google there were two camps having flame wars in favour of `required` and agains it.

Comment: @ovanes I know it's disappointing to us c++ people - we're used to strong typing. But of course protobuf in the end is just a serialisation protocol. The server/receiver must be the ultimate arbiter of what is correct or not. A malicious client could send anything. For that reason, in our protobuf rpc implementations, the server checks all invariants and sends back an exception notification if the message is ill-formed or incomplete.

Comment: Yes, but this is also against DRY. How many people out there use Protobuf and all have to implement this kind of `required` checks. I understand if someone needs to check more complex invariants, like if that field has a value X than the other should have Y. But if there is such thing as `required` it should also work :( And not asking: Yeah! Just bloat your code with tons of if statements and do your checks. AFAIK Protobuf does not even support Visitor pattern, to do that kind of dispatch and verification without `if`s.

Comment: @ovanes you can iterate through a message descriptor's field descriptors and check for requiredness, so you can check all messages with one function which takes a reference to the base class `Message`